# R - Given a row, count how many other rows have same two column values and a timestamp within 30 seconds of its own timestamp

Tags: r

In R, for each row in table 'spd', I have two variables ("Account" and "Asset"), as well as "DateTime" stamp.

I'd like to add a new column (in this example "Return"), which evaluates if another row has the same exact Account and Asset, and has a timestamp within 30 seconds of its own.

For example if DateTime for a given row is 
    7/20/2018 8:05:00

"within 30 seconds" would be anywhere between 
    7/20/2018 8:04:30 and 7/20/2018 8:05:30.

Here is an example table showing Account, Asset, DateTime, as well as the new Return Column based on the calculation explained above.

```
Account  Asset  DateTime            Return
100      A100   7/20/2018 8:57:25   TRUE
100      A100   7/20/2018 8:57:55   TRUE
100      A100   7/20/2018 8:58:20   TRUE
100      B100   7/20/2018 8:56:31   FALSE
200      A200   7/21/2018 8:56:30   TRUE
200      A200   7/21/2018 8:57:00   TRUE
200      A200   7/21/2018 8:59:00   FALSE
200      A200   7/21/2018 8:59:45   FALSE
```

So far I've only been able to count rows with matching Account and Asset. 
For example, using data.table package:

```
Library(data.table)
setDT(spd)
spd[,vehicle_count := .N, by = .(Account, Asset)]
```

I've also experimented with dplyr group by, and several others, but cannot find a way to incorporate the +- 30 seconds step of the equation.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Edited per AndersSwanson discussion below.

Ultimately I need to subset and keep only records that have at least one more occurrence (same account, same asset, timestamp within 30 seconds).

If a record does not have a match it would be eliminated: (account and asset do not match another row) 
or (account and asset do match, but timestamp does not have a match within 30 seconds)

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what is meant by "have a timestamp within 30 seconds of its own". So if account 300 with Asset A300 has time stamps at 9:00:01, 9:00:29, and 9:00:58. would the Return column values be 2, 2, and 2 respectively?

Comment: Totally might be off here, but would it make sense to think about this differently? e.g. For each possible combination of Account and Asset, how many times did events happen within 30 seconds of one another?

Comment: At the moment the code throws an error and the error message is very informative: `spd[,vehicle_count := .N, by = .(spd$Account, spd$Asset_)]
Error in `[.data.table`(spd, , `:=`(vehicle_count, .N), by = .(spd$Account,  : 
  column or expression 2 of 'by' or 'keyby' is type NULL. Do not quote column names. Usage: DT[,sum(colC),by=list(colA,month(colB))]`. What's not clear from the error message is the misspelling of the `Asset` column name.

Comment: @42: Thanks for the catch and I removed the typo '_'. Was just using that to illustrate one of the several approaches I've been able to take accomplish part of the task, but the key part that I've not been successful with is counting other timestamps within 30 seconds for records that have the same asset and same account

Comment: @AndersSwanson : good points and I'm thinking differently about the problem as a result. Although in your case, If I can have it evaluate to your outcome, 2,2,2, that would also be sufficient. Ultimately what I need to do is be able to subset and keep only instances that have at least one additional instance within 30 seconds, for the same asset/account.

Comment: Still need to drop the two instances of `spd$`. Using access to the dataframe inheritance of data.table objects is just wrong.

Comment: _of its own timestamp_ you mean the first time stamp in the group or the previous one.

Comment: A non-equi join should work. First step would be using a datetime column class instead of a string or factor (as the answers below do fixing your data to use POSIXct).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dplyr and lubridate this is pretty easy.

The `lead()` and `lag()` functions make it pretty easy to do this. If we arrange the data by DateTime ascending then we can use `lead()` to see if the next value was within 30 seconds and the `lag()` function to see whether the last value was within 30 seconds. This is also vectorized code and should run fairly quickly.

This works unless there is only one item in a group of Account and Asset, but we get NA if there was only 1 item in the group. That's actually a clean failure and we can simply replace any NA with FALSE. Sweet!

Since my method requires arranging everything by DateTime, I also have to re-arrange it back the way you had it to begin with.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data <- tibble(
  Account = c('100'    ,'100'    ,'100'    ,'100'   ,'200'    ,'200'    ,'200'    ,'200'    ),
  Asset = c('A100' , 'A100' , 'A100' , 'B100' , 'A200' , 'A200' , 'A200' , 'A200' ),
  DateTime = c('7/20/2018 8:57:25', '7/20/2018 8:57:55', '7/20/2018 8:58:20', '7/20/2018 8:56:31', '7/21/2018 8:56:30', '7/21/2018 8:57:00', '7/21/2018 8:59:00', '7/21/2018 8:59:45')
)

data <- data %>% 
  mutate(DateTime = mdy_hms(DateTime))

output <- data %>%
  group_by(Account,Asset) %>%
  arrange(DateTime) %>%
  mutate(Return = (abs(difftime(DateTime, lag(DateTime,1L) , units = 'secs')) <= 30) |
                  (abs(difftime(DateTime, lead(DateTime,1L), units = 'secs')) <= 30),
         # the previous line will return NA if there were less than 2 DateTime available
         # so replace any NA with FALSE to fix single entries
         Return = ifelse(is.na(Return),FALSE,Return)
        ) %>%
  arrange(Account,Asset,DateTime) %>%
  ungroup()

output  
# # A tibble: 8 x 4
# # Groups:   Account, Asset [3]
# Account Asset DateTime            Return
#  <chr>   <chr> <dttm>              <lgl> 
# 1 100     A100  2018-07-20 08:57:25 TRUE  
# 2 100     A100  2018-07-20 08:57:55 TRUE  
# 3 100     A100  2018-07-20 08:58:20 TRUE  
# 4 100     B100  2018-07-20 08:56:31 FALSE 
# 5 200     A200  2018-07-21 08:56:30 TRUE  
# 6 200     A200  2018-07-21 08:57:00 TRUE  
# 7 200     A200  2018-07-21 08:59:00 FALSE 
# 8 200     A200  2018-07-21 08:59:45 FALSE
```

Comment: Awesome thanks! For my particular use case I omitted the : data <- data %>% 
  mutate(DateTime = mdy_hms(DateTime))
commands and this works quite well. This command was most likely included in the response, as others included similar commands in their solutions, as a fault of my own for not being explicit on the data classes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here I understand "of its own timestamp" as the previous one, If you mean the first time stamp in the group then you can do `diff=DateTime-DateTime[1]`

```
library(dplyr)
df$DateTime <- as.POSIXct(df$DateTime,format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S")
df %>% group_by(Account, Asset) %>% 
       mutate(diff=DateTime-lag(DateTime), 
       Flag = case_when(n()==1 ~ F,is.na(diff) ~ T,abs(diff)<=30 ~ T, TRUE  ~ F))

    # A tibble: 8 x 6
    # Groups:   Account, Asset [3]
  Account Asset DateTime            Return diff       Flag 
     <int> <chr> <dttm>               <int> <time>     <lgl>
1     100 A100  2015-09-20 08:57:25      3 " NA secs" TRUE 
2     100 A100  2015-09-20 08:57:55      3 " 30 secs" TRUE 
3     100 A100  2015-09-20 08:58:20      3 " 25 secs" TRUE 
4     100 B100  2015-09-20 08:56:31      1 " NA secs" FALSE
5     200 A200  2015-09-21 08:56:30      2 " NA secs" TRUE 
6     200 A200  2015-09-21 08:57:00      2 " 30 secs" TRUE 
7     200 A200  2015-09-21 08:59:00      2 120 secs   FALSE
8     200 A200  2015-09-21 08:59:45      2 " 45 secs" FALSE
```

## Data

```
df <- read.table(text="
    Account  Asset  DateTime            Return
    100      A100   '9/20/2015 8:57:25'   3
    100      A100   '9/20/2015 8:57:55'   3
    100      A100   '9/20/2015 8:58:20'   3
    100      B100   '9/20/2015 8:56:31'   1
    200      A200   '9/21/2015 8:56:30'   2
    200      A200   '9/21/2015 8:57:00'   2
    200      A200   '9/21/2015 8:59:00'   2
    200      A200   '9/21/2015 8:59:45'   2
                             ",header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are getting at -

```
library(dplyr)
spd$DateTime = as.POSIXct(strptime(spd$DateTime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
spd$StartTime = spd$DateTime - 30
spd$EndTime = spd$DateTime + 30
spd = spd %>% group_by(Account, Asset) %>% 
        rowwise() %>% 
        mutate(Count = sum(DateTime >= spd$StartTime & DateTime <= spd$EndTime)-1) %>% 
        select(-StartTime, -EndTime)
spd$Return = spd$Count > 0


> spd

  Account Asset DateTime            Count Return
    <int> <chr> <dttm>              <dbl> <lgl> 
1     100 A100  2018-07-20 08:57:25  1.00 T     
2     100 A100  2018-07-20 08:57:55  2.00 T     
3     100 A100  2018-07-20 08:58:20  1.00 T     
4     100 B100  2018-07-20 08:56:31  0    F     
5     200 A200  2018-07-21 08:56:30  1.00 T     
6     200 A200  2018-07-21 08:57:00  1.00 T     
7     200 A200  2018-07-21 08:59:00  0    F     
8     200 A200  2018-07-21 08:59:45  0    F
```

Comment: When using the line: spd$DateTime = as.POSIXct(strptime(spd$DateTime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p"))
, it is changing my DateTime field to NA thus causing issues downstream for the rest of the commands.

Comment: I can have it evaluate by eliminating that line, however the results are not correct when I do this.

Comment: I think that is because of the extra `%p`. I have edited it out. Does it work now?

Comment: What is the class of the `DateTime` column?

Comment: If it helps, If I input class(spd$DateTime) before adding any new code, I get back: [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

Comment: eliminating the %p has the same outcome, NA for DateTime

Comment: What happens when you do `spd$StartTime = spd$DateTime - 30` before doing any other operation? Do you get a column with 30 secs subtracted from each timestamp?

Comment: Correct, new column with 30 seconds subtracted if performed before any other operation. The class of which is the same:  [1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

Comment: And it does not work if you just leave out `spd$DateTime = as.POSIXct(strptime(spd$DateTime, format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S"))`?

Comment: The use case I have right in development is about 8K lines. Upon review, it does evaluate many lines correctly for both True and False. It does not seem to have any false negatives. However it does contain many False Positives, classifying lines as True where account and asset match, but no DateTime within 30 seconds. For example, two records classified as true have same asset and account, but DateTime is over 3 minutes apart.

Comment: The case you are mentioning should have made observations 7 and 8 come up as `T` but it shows `F` in the output above, so I am at a loss, unless you upload a sample with these false positive observations.

I am curious about what the `Count` in the false positive observations say.

Comment: Thanks, I have no doubt your solution would work with some minor trouble shooting, and is likely a fault of my own for missing something in my own data or I'm not properly articulating in the example I gave. Appreciate the time either way!